# get value of Descriptor from xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to get value of "Descriptor" (ie. "Employee") from below code into my XSLT and assign it to other variable "Worker_Type1"

```
    <wd:Worker_Type wd:Descriptor="Employee">
       <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d588c41a446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
       <wd:ID wd:type="Worker_Type_ID">EE</wd:ID>
    </wd:Worker_Type>
```

Code used in XSLT to get descriptor value

```
                <xsl:for-each select= "*:Worker_Type">  
                    <xsl:element name="Worker_Type1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Descriptor"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

But i dont get the value in the output and it neither errors

Comment: I, too, am implementing Workday ;-) and I had this exact question. Thanks for asking it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't specified the prefix, you can either try the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*:Descriptor"/>
```

Or, if the prefix is, for example, `wd` for the namespace in your stylesheet, you may, as well, use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@wd:Descriptor"/>
```